# Problem in use Deprecated or Experimental directive

Tags: delphi

As you know in **Delphi** we can use **Deprecated** directive to say a method or ... is obsolete or supported only for backward compatibility and we can use **Experimental** directive to say current unit are in an unstable development state .

Deprecated & Experimental directives work properly in form,s unit , but when we use it on unit that we add to application manualy they don,t work and when compile application don,t show any warning message in message window .

May i should enable any directive like {$HINTS ON} or {$WARNINGS ON} in that unit ?
Any one can help me ?

Thanks alot .

Comment: I didn't know about 'experimental'. When did that one arrive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've answered the question yourself. These directives make the compiler emit warnings, but only if warnings are enabled at that point in the compilation. Note that these symbols produce warnings rather than hints.

I personally configure the compiler to treat the use of `deprecated` symbols as an error rather than a warning.

[image]